# Dotnet core Invalid input switch: -t

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out how dotnet core is working and therefore creating some projects to play around with it. I found a guide where they said, that i should run "dotnet new -t web" to create a more fully-featured web application. But when i do, it just says:

```
Invalid input switch:
  -t 

Template Instantiation Commands for .NET Core CLI.

Usage: dotnet new [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
  template  The template to instantiate.
```

Have they changed it? And why doesn't any documents appear when i run "dotnet new", but only if i do "dotnet new mvc" or "dotnet new web". I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they changed the CLI tool as part of the move from `project.json` back to `csproj`. More info on the official [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/cli-msbuild-architecture).

The best source is the up to date documentation for [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new):

> Creates a new project, configuration file or solution based on the specified template.
>
> ```
> dotnet new <TEMPLATE> [-lang|--language] [-n|--name] [-o|--output] [-all|--show-all] [-h|--help] [Template arguments]
> dotnet new <TEMPLATE> [-l|--list]
> dotnet new [-all|--show-all]
> dotnet new [-h|--help]
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> dotnet new mvc                   ==> New C# MVC app
> dotnet new console -lang f#      ==> New F# console app
> ```

Comment: Ah alright, thanks! So now that i've created a new project with "dotnet new webapi" i got the following:

bin,
obj,
controllers (http requests),
wwwroot,
program.js,
startup.js

It seems that wwwroot is empty by default. How do i then add bower to my project, so i can install bootstrap, jquery and angular?

Comment: Sounds to me you want to use the mvc template and not the webapi one

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the guide that you're following was referencing the previous version of dotnet core cli. In previous versions `-t` was required to specify the template. Now it works differently.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new) you can use command `new` in one of the following ways:

```
dotnet new <TEMPLATE> [-lang|--language] [-n|--name] [-o|--output] [-all|--show-all] [-h|--help] [Template arguments]
dotnet new <TEMPLATE> [-l|--list]
dotnet new [-all|--show-all]
dotnet new [-h|--help]
```

However, even when you call `dotnet new` it should show some information (checked in VS Code and command line).

Hope that will help.